# AR.JS HTML Content Showing Before Camera Accepted

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I have an AR.JS setup and I am using a aframe html shader plugin to render HTML as a texture onto my plane. I am having one issue that when loading the view before accepting the camera permissions that I can see the HTML code, when I accept the camera permissions the camera loads and I cannot see it anymore until I use the AR Marker that uses the HTML then it appears correctly. Is there any way I can solve this? I was thinking maybe listening until when the camera is accepted and then display the html otherwise have it hidden (then it will never show) but I am not sure how to make this work or if its possible.

Any solutions?

Thanks

```
<!-- include a-frame -->
<script src="vendor/aframe/build/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-html-shader@0.2.0/dist/aframe-html-shader.min.js"></script>

<!-- include ar.js for aframe -->
<script src='../build/aframe-ar.js'></script>
<script>ARjs.Context.baseURL = '../../three.js/'</script>
<script>document.addEventListener('click', evt => document.querySelector('video').play());
</script>

<!-- start the body of your page -->
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <!-- add some info at the top of the page -->
    <div style='position: fixed; top: 10px; width:100%; text-align: center; z-index: 1; color:white; font-size:30px;'>
        <a>Prototype ALL</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Define your 3d scene and enabled ar.js -->
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
        <a-assets> 
        <video id="video" autoplay loop="true" src="video.mp4">       </video>
        </a-assets> 
        <!-- Create a anchor to attach your augmented reality -->
        <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='qrvideo.patt'>         
        <a-video src="#video" width="1.8" height="1" rotation="270 0 0">      </a-video>

    </a-marker>


        <a-marker preset='custom' type='pattern' url='qrcode.patt'>
           <a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2; height: 0.5" rotation="-90 0 0" material="shader: html; target: #htmlElement"></a-entity>
    </a-marker>

<!-- add marker here -->


        <!-- Define a static camera -->
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>

    </a-scene>
    <!-- custom html rendering -->
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -2; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="htmlElement" style="background: #F8F8F8; color: #333; font-size: 48px">testing1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can probably hook into the permission popup and the permission status in general. I know 8thwall does it, but their handling of that is in the proprietary part of their code. (Looking for a solution to that currently myself.)